# Incomplete OneToMany collections when using JPA findOne with EntityGraph

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

During the migration from Spring-Boot:2.7.4 to Spring-Boot:3.0.9, I notice that `EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor.findOne(Specification<T> spec, EntityGraph entityGraph)` does not completely resolve OneToMany collection.

With spring-boot:2.7.4 this worked very well. I can't find any information about this problem in the migration instructions.

This can be seen in the small demo. When calling `findOne(with(authorId), entityGraph)` not all books are resolved for the author - test will fail.

I expect all lazy fetched `OneToMany` details to be resolved.

You can find small demo here: https://github.com/da-von/spring-boot-jpa-findOne

When logging the generated SQL queries, it is visible that `left join` is combined with `fetch first ? rows only` limitation.
This seems to make no sense to me, as EntityGraphs can be dynamic and the results must also be completely resolved for dependent details.

```
select a1_0.id,b1_0.author_id,b1_0.id,b1_0.genre,b1_0.isbn,b1_0.title,a1_0.name 
  from author a1_0 
      left join book b1_0 on a1_0.id=b1_0.author_id 
  where a1_0.id=? 
  fetch first ? rows only
```

- Local Machine: MacBook Pro, macOS Ventura:13.4.1
- `java:17` locally existing VM `temurin-17.jdk`
- `spring-boot:3.0.9`
- `com.cosium.spring.data:spring-data-jpa-entity-graph:3.0.1`
- Postgres in Docker image `Postgres:13-alpine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Override repository interface with:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface OverrideEntityGraphSimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, EntityGraphPagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    @Override
    default Optional<T> findOne(Specification<T> spec) {
        return findOne(spec, (EntityGraph) null);
    }

    @Override
    default Optional<T> findOne(Specification<T> spec, EntityGraph entityGraph) {
        val items = findAll(spec, entityGraph);

        if (items.size() > 1) {
            throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1);
        }
        if (items.size() == 1) {
            return Optional.of(items.get(0));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

AuthorRepository and BookRepository extend this interface, executing the overridden `findOne(...)` variants:

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends OverrideEntityGraphSimpleJpaRepository<Author, Long>,
        EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor<Author> {

    default Optional<Author> findOne(long id, EntityGraph entityGraph) {
        return findOne(
                  (a, cb, cq) -> cq.equal(a.get(Author_.id), id), 
                   entityGraph
        );
    } 

    // other detail ommitted

}
```

Solution is committed to the sample repository https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph

Comment: How clean is this solution?